# stop execution of worklight procedure

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

can we stop execution of worklight procedure(adapter).I have a form.on submit click i calls webservice through worklight adapter .and a cancel button.how can i stop execution on cancel button click?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is not possible at this time in Worklight.

Comment: is there any work around for it.because if user wana cancel the operation then how would he cancel?

Comment: What is your scenario? What are you developing?

Comment: Scenario like i have a page that show a large set of data with search criteria .when call procedure it takes time.mean while if user wana cancel this operation and want to issue another searching criteria then what to do because once procedure execution starts it does'nt stop.

Comment: Well, just like how you can't "stop" a google search after you have sent the request... you can't stop a procedure after you have sent it away... what you can do maybe is have some flag, that if is 'true' (the user pressed on Cancel), then once the request data returns it will not be displayed or some other mechanism of sorts... you will have to handle all possible cases.

Comment: Hmm.Thanks Idan,..i got you.

Comment: If your question is answered, please mark it as Answered. Thanks.

Comment: @IdanAdar. How is this not possible? Ajax requests have an abort method - See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FXMLHttpRequest#abort() All Worklight needs to do is expose the underlying XHR request. `WL.Client.invokeProcedure` could return this object.

Comment: @IdanAdar I see that you edited your answer to say *at this time in Worklight*. I do believe it's a common requirement and as such should probably be raised as a feature request. Could you please point us to the right channel for doing this? P.S. Prefix nicknames with an @ when replying because otherwise we don't get notified. Cheers

Comment: @Marko, if you'd like to submit a feature request for Worklight, follow the steps provided here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014907906&ps=25